# How can I get the latest date from a selection of dates in Power Query?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerpivot

Could you please tell me how I can get the max date from a column that have dates like this:

Columns (formatted as text):

01/11/2020, 10/11/2020

Desired output:

10/11/2020

this code shows null:

```
#"Added Custom9" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom8", "REAL_DATE_3", each  let dates =#"Added Custom8"[DATE_REAL_2] in [min = List.Min(dates), max = List.Max(dates)]),
expanded1 = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Added Custom9", "REAL_DATE_3", {"min", "max"})
```

Comment: Are you columns formatted as text or as datetime? Will there always be two dates, and will the first one always be earlier?

Comment: Also, have you done a search for this yourself? I web-searched your title, verbatim, and the top result was this YouTube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XEbwaPxXTUw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this below code in **Power Query Editor**. Go to **Advanced Editor** to your respected table and incorporate this below code-

let your column name: **date_list**

```
let
    //--your existing steps,
    split = Table.AddColumn(#"previous_step_name", "datesToCheck", each List.Transform(Text.Split([date_list], ", "), each Date.FromText(_, "en-US")), type list),
    minAndMax = Table.AddColumn(split, "toExpand", each [max = List.Max([datesToCheck])], type record),
    expanded = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(minAndMax, "toExpand", {"max"})
in
    expanded
```

Here is the output my case-

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much,  i verified the code and worked.

Comment: Hi @BenCruz nice to see it worked. You can also put an up vote if it really helped :)